# BASH Shell Infinite loop with IF ELSE Statment

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, while-loop, infinite-loop

Ok I know I've asked a similar question, I understand how to do an infinate loop:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    foo
    bar
        then
sleep 10
done
```

But if I want to run some (quite a few) IF ELSE Statements in this loop how would I get the script to carry on looping once they had completed how would I go about this?

Comment: you mean how you can do an if/else statement inside the while ? I dont understand

Comment: Yes thats it, I have have pretty big script with a fair few if else statements in it. What I want to do is loop the entire script.

Comment: @bikerben: Well, just wrap the shell code you want in a `while`/`do`/`done`. And if you intend to break out of it with Ctrl-C (or any other method of killing it), perhaps have a look at the `trap` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while :; do
    if cond1; then
        whatever
    elif cond2; then
        something else
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

1. You do infinite loop using `while true` or using true's shorter alias `:`. `[ 1 ]` is needlessly complicated and is not what you think it is (`[ 0 ]` is also true!). Remember, the condition in `if` and `while` is arbitrary command whose exit status (zero = true, nonzero = false) is used as the condition value and `[` is just alias for special `test` command (both built-in in most shells, but they don't have to be).
2. Any shell construct is allowed between `do`/`done` including conditionals, more loops and cases.
3. Use `break` to terminate innermost loop from inside (just like most other languages).

Comment: I bet he's not asking that... I don't understand why he says: "What I want to do is loop the entire script"

Answer (score 0):

An if in bash is just: `if [ some test ]; then some_command; fi`:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    if [ some test ]
    then
        some command
    else
        other cmd
    fi
sleep 10
done
```

[Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: No. if in shell is just `if some test; then some command; fi`. The `[` is a command used for comparing values and checking existence of files, but there are many cases where you either need some arbitrary command (`which`, `grep`, ...) or where `test` is not enough and end up going with `expr`.

Answer (score 0):

Correction to chown case added brake to finish the loop
Corrected

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    if [ some test ]
    then
        some command
    brake
    else
        other cmd
    fi
sleep 10
done
```